# Identify an animated cartoon I watched in the mid 80s (space alien/ghost battle??)

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, space, animation

Seen on TV or VHS in the early/mid 80s (United States). Could have been from the 70's too.

I do not recall much about the general plot.  I believe it involves a set of siblings (as kids), I think four of them.  They are captured and have to escape and/or battle some alien/ghost entity(s).

I'll describe the three scenes I remember.  It will sound pretty weird/abstract...but that is just how memory works. lol.

Scene 1:
There is a maze that the kids have to navigate through.  The camera angle is from above the maze.  And the characters are at different locations in the maze and keep popping their heads up over the walls.

Scene 2:
The characters trapped in into a room where mechanical hands reach out and tickle them.

Scene 3: (which I think is the ending)
The characters are in small pod shaped space ships and they are fighting aliens/ghosts in other pod ships.  Which may or may not have been invisible.

Any ideas?